# Flask-Restful error while trying to run this api

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I was learning to create apis in flask and was following [this link](https://betterdatascience.com/develop-database-driven-rest-api-with-python-in-10-minutes/).

I hit the run button and the the code worked but gave this warning about marshmellow-sqlalchemy
[image]

I then opened postman and put the url "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users" [image]

And here is the issue, it says `"message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."`

There is a similar post already on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893180/flask-restful-error-request-content-type-was-not-application-json), but I couldn't bring out the proper similarity between the two, so pls help!!

I copied the entire code form the above mentioned link but here is a copy of the same:-

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow 
from flask_restful import Resource, Api


app = Flask(__name__) 
api = Api(app) 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db' 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False 
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(32))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, username, password, first_name, last_name, age):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age')

db.create_all()

user_schema = UserSchema() 
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

class UserManager(Resource): 
    
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        try: id = request.args['id']
        except Exception as _: id = None

        if not id:
            users = User.query.all()
            return jsonify(users_schema.dump(users))
        user = User.query.get(id)
        return jsonify(user_schema.dump(user))

    @staticmethod
    def post():
        username = request.json['username']
        password = request.json['password']
        first_name = request.json['first_name']
        last_name = request.json['last_name']
        age = request.json['age']

        user = User(username, password, first_name, last_name, age)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({
            'Message': f'User {first_name} {last_name} inserted.'
        })

    @staticmethod
    def put():
        try: id = request.args['id']
        except Exception as _: id = None

        if not id:
            return jsonify({ 'Message': 'Must provide the user ID' })

        user = User.query.get(id)
        username = request.json['username']
        password = request.json['password']
        first_name = request.json['first_name']
        last_name = request.json['last_name']
        age = request.json['age']

        user.username = username
        user.password = password
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.age = age

        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({
            'Message': f'User {first_name} {last_name} altered.'
        })

    @staticmethod
    def delete():
        try: id = request.args['id']
        except Exception as _: id = None

        if not id:
            return jsonify({ 'Message': 'Must provide the user ID' })

        user = User.query.get(id)
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({
            'Message': f'User {str(id)} deleted.'
        })


api.add_resource(UserManager, '/api/users')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: In postman change the media type to json

Comment: @testfile ur suggestion worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I added a field in header in Postman as `Content-Type:application/json`
and it worked
[image]