# JSONDecodeError while following YouTube guide on API development with flask

Tags: python, flask

Been following this video for building rest API's with flask https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMppyAPbLYk had some other problems earlier on in the video but fized it with guidance from this [Flask-Restful Error: request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893180/flask-restful-error-request-content-type-was-not-application-json).

I'm quite sure I'm following the code exactly so not sure why I've ran into errors. The part of the video is around the 40-42 minute mark. Here is the main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

video_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
video_put_args.add_argument("name", type=str, help="Name of the video", required=True, location='form')
video_put_args.add_argument("views", type=int, help="Views of the video", required=True, location='form')
video_put_args.add_argument("likes", type=int, help="Likes on the video", required=True, location='form')

videos = {}

def abort_if_vid_id_dont_exsist(video_id):
    if video_id not in videos:
        abort(404, message="video id is not valid")

def abort_if_vid_exsist(video_id):
    if video_id in videos:
        abort(409, message='video with id already exsists')

class Video(Resource):
    def get(self, video_id):
        abort_if_vid_id_dont_exsist(video_id)
        return videos[video_id]
    
    def put(self, video_id):
        abort_if_vid_exsist(video_id)
        args = video_put_args.parse_args()
        videos[video_id] = args
        return videos[video_id], 201
    
    def delete(self, video_id):
        abort_if_vid_id_dont_exsist(video_id)
        del videos[video_id]
        return '', 204
    
api.add_resource(Video, "/video/<int:video_id>")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

and this is the py.test:

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

data = [{"likes":78, "name": "Sam", "views": 100000},
        {"likes":10000, "name": "How to make REST api", "views": 800000},
        {"likes":10, "name": "jimmy", "views": 2000}]

for i in range(len(data)):
    response = requests.put(BASE + "video/" + str(i), data[i])
    print(response.json())

input()
response = requests.delete(BASE + "video/0" )
print(response.json())
input()
response = requests.get(BASE + "video/2" )
print(response.json())
```

And finally I was getting this in the error message, the first part posted but it was not printing the responses. I have looked through this but not sure what gone wrong as I'm following a video guide. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
{'name': 'Sam', 'views': 100000, 'likes': 78}
{'name': 'How to make REST api', 'views': 800000, 'likes': 10000}
{'name': 'jimmy', 'views': 2000, 'likes': 10}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", 
line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)      

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\Desktop\pythonpractice\python practice\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(response.json())
  File "C:\Users\Samuel.Rouse\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I followed the guide so not sure what to do next.